# Upgrade SQLite version on Lambda Python3.9

Tags: python, sqlite, aws-lambda

The built-in version of SQLite on the AWS Lambda runtime Python 3.9 is v3.7.17 which was released in 2013. I am unable to upgrade this version with a Layer or Code Deployment because library sources are arranged in such a away where it's not overridable since Python 3.9 is bundled with SQLite (batteries included and all). I believe Lambda finds `sqlite.so` in `/var/runtime/lib`

Is there a way to update SQLite in Lambda?

Python dumb of Lambda env vars:

```
'LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR': '/var/runtime',
'LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT': '/var/task',
'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8',
'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib',
'PATH': '/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin',
'PWD': '/var/task',
'PYTHONPATH': '/var/runtime',
'SHLVL': '0',
'TZ': ':UTC',
```

And sys.path

```
[
'/var/task',
'/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
'/opt/python',
'/var/runtime',
'/var/lang/lib/python38.zip',
'/var/lang/lib/python3.8',
'/var/lang/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
'/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
'/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
'/opt/python'
]
```

Proof:

```py
import sqlite3
print("sqlite3:")
sqlite3_version = ".".join(str(x) for x in sqlite3.version_info)
sqlite3_lib_version = ".".join(str(x) for x in sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)
print(f"Version: v{sqlite3_version}")
print(f"SQLite Library Version: v{sqlite3_lib_version}")
```

```
sqlite3:
Version: v2.6.0
SQLite Library Version: v3.7.17
```

Comment: I think a custom runtime here would be the only option if layers won't work but I haven't dug into it - good question!

Answer (score 0):

I have used `pysqlite3-binary` to get a recent version of sqlite3 when using Lambda. This is probably really easy if you are both developing and deploying on Linux. Then you can just install the package everywhere. But if you only need the package when deploying your Lambda on Linux, then you have to deal with the fact that the package isn't available for other platforms.

If you're using Pipenv and Docker, here's how to do it:

*Pipfile*

```
[packages]
requests = "*"
boto3 = "*"

[sqlite]
pysqlite3-binary = { version = "*", platform_machine = "== 'x86_64'" }
```

To create the lockfile locally, you'd use the same commands you always would:

```
$ pipenv update
```

In code, use the module if it's available, otherwise fall back to the system version:

```py
try:
    import pysqlite3 as sqlite3
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import sqlite3  # for local testing because pysqlite3-binary couldn't be installed on macOS

print(f"{sqlite3.sqlite_version=}")
```

Then in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip install pipenv

COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

# Lock the sqlite category to fetch hashes for the Linux platform
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv lock --categories sqlite
# Install everything from the packages and sqlite categories, and
# rely on package hashes in the Pipfile.lock
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install --deploy --categories="packages sqlite" --verbose
```

Note that the `--categories` flag is new in pipenv as of October 2022, so make sure you get the latest version of pipenv. [Github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4745), [docs](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/specifiers/#specifying-package-categories)

Comment: Hey thanks for responding here! I ended up just giving up on the Lambda Runtime Team and exclusively use docker containers now. Much easier and faster!